# How to fix uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've got a Bootstrap popover script that returns an error in the java console when I click on the button. So the button shows up fine, and when I click on it I can see the content of the html file the popover is linking to, but it triggers an error that appears twice in the console that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null.

I've tried replacing `outerHTML` with `innerHTML` but that did not help.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
<button type="button" data-templatefile="Text.html" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" style='float:right;margin-right:50px'>
  My popover button
</button>

<script>
  function loadContent(templateFile) {
    return $('<div>').load(templateFile, function(html) {
      parser = new DOMParser();
      doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      return doc.querySelector('h1').outerHTML + doc.querySelector('body').outerHTML;
    })
  }
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html : true,
    content : function() {
      return loadContent($(this).data('templatefile'))
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: "_I've tried ... innerHTML_". Why? The error message clearly states, that `doc.querySelector('h1')` is `null`.

Comment: please provaide also template file

Comment: what do you *imagine* `loadContent` returns?

Comment: and, is `content` parameter of `.popover` supposed to be a function?

Comment: `the error message clearly states, that doc.querySelector('h1') is null` no it doesn't - why can't it be `doc.querySelector('body')` that is null :p

Comment: the template file contains one line: <h1>my text here</h1>

Comment: so, it has no `body`

Comment: by the way ... `parser = new DOMParser();
            doc = parser.parseFromString('<h1>my text here</h1>', "text/html");
            console.log(doc.querySelector('h1').outerHTML + doc.querySelector('body').outerHTML);` works without error - so that's not the problem (unless `html` isn't `'<h1>my text here</h1>'` of course)

Comment: and also the result would be `<h1>my text here</h1><body><h1>my text here</h1></body>` odd looking duck, that

Comment: the only way this would result with the error as shown is if (as @Teemu rightly said) `doc.querySelector('h1')` is null (because `doc.querySelector('body')` would never be null with such code ... my advice is to `console.log(html)` to confirm it is indeed `<h1>my text here</h1>`

Comment: so, either `Text.html` doesn't exist, isn't called `Text.html` (but maybe `text.html`) or is in an unexpected folder

Comment: The weird thing is that the popover does show the content of the html file, so it does display 'my text here' when I click on the popover. But when I click on it, I also get two error messages in the console (Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null), one for h1 and one for body indeed

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've fixed it by adding a  to the linked html that holds the content of the popover. It now reads:

```
<body><h1>my text here</h1></body>
```

and no more errors come up in the java console when I click on the popover. Thanks